# Is "ragazzi" a way to refer to a young couple?

Tags: meaning, translation

In the following sentence, does the term *i due ragazzi* translate to *the young couple*?

> I due ragazzi non hanno segreti.

Can this only be used to refer to a young couple?
Does this just mean *the two young people* and not have any implication of romance without context?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression “i *due ragazzi*” would be the same as “*the two kids*”.

The young couple would be translated as “*la giovane coppia*”.

In the case you mentioned you’re right, it just means that the two youths have no secrets to each other.

Without a specific context you can say nothing about the kind of romantic relationship, you only state that they are close friends.

Surely when you use the term *ragazzi* you usually refer to young people, but in general you can also use the term to ironically describe an older man acting as a younger one.

> Suo nonno è proprio un ragazzo incorreggibile.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase *i due ragazzi* is very generic and can refer to any two youths (provided one of them is male, otherwise it would be *le due ragazze*).

Unless the context makes clear that the two youths are a just mentioned young couple, it would be impossible to understand that they form a couple.

> Sono stato a trovare una coppia di giovani sposini. I due ragazzi non hanno segreti (l'un l'altro) e si amano molto.