# Uso di "sono stata/o a" + infinito

Tags: verbs, tenses

Su [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9992/707) ho letto la frase seguente (grassetto mio)

> **Sono stato a trovare** una coppia di giovani sposini

e ho avuto dei dubbi sull'uso delle espressioni del tipo "sono stata/o a" + infinito.

Prima di tutto, il verbo che appare in queste locuzioni è "essere" oppure "stare"? Immagino sia "stare", ma non ne sono per niente sicura.

Poi, le espressioni della forma "sono andato/a a" + infinito possono essere sempre sostituite da "sono stato a" + infinito? Ad esempio, invece di "sono andata a fare la spesa" o "sono andata a prendere un po' di sole" potrei dire "sono stata a fare la spesa" o "sono stata a prendere un po' di sole"?

Un altro dubbio: il verbo può essere usato soltanto al passato? Unicamente al passato prossimo? Potrei dire "stetti a trovare un amico"? Ma "starò a trovare un amico" non sembra avere molto senso, vero?

Comment: L'estate prossima, covid permettendo, sarò a trovare un'amica a Barcellona. 

Comment: Trovo che rientri nel punto 11. di https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare

Comment: @DaG:    Sono ogni volta più confusa: queste locuzioni esprimono il prolungarsi di un'azione?

Comment: Altre prove a favore di “stare”. In una [“finestra di approfondimento” sul verbo “stare”](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) del Treccani c'è sia l'esempio “ci siamo trattenuti a lungo a parlare con mio nonno” per esemplificare “trattenersi” come sinonimo più formale di “stare” (e infatti si potrebbe dire benissimo “siamo stati a lungo a parlare...”) sia l'esempio “sta tutto il giorno a guardare la televisione”.

Comment: Non so, @DaG: trovo in questi esempi del Treccani un'indicazione di tempo che dà appunto l'idea di un'azione che si prolunga o che continua che non si trova nelle frasi della domanda.

Answer (score 1):

Non ne sono sicuro al 100%, ma la mia intuizione dice che in queste locuzioni il verbo è *essere*, non *stare*. Per esempio è perfettamente legittimo dire

> Sono a trovare un amico

Mentre la frase

> *Sto a trovare un amico

mi suona regionale, quando non proprio scorretta. Questo dovrebbe anche spiegare perché frasi come **Stetti a trovare un amico* suonano molto strane (a dire il vero anche *Fui a trovare un amico* mi suona innaturale, ma sospetto che questa sia solo la mia naturale avversione per il passato remoto). Per quanto riguarda il futuro

> Sarò a trovare un amico
> è perfettamente usabile e infatti molto comune nella mia esperienza.

Finalmente, riguardo alla differenza tra *sono andata a prendere il pane* e *sono stata a prendere il pane*, le due frasi ancorché simili non mi sembrano esattamente sinonimi. Per esempio non userei mai la seconda se sono ancora dal panettiere (piuttosto userei il presente: *sono a prendere un po' di pane*).

Comment: Come al solito c'entreranno varietà regionali, idioletti etc., ma a me personalmente anche “Sono/sarò a trovare un amico” suona molto insolito. Una costruzione del genere ce l'ho nell'orecchio solo in una frase del tipo “Sono a presentarvi il celebre oratore” (che trovo appena un gradino al di sopra di “andiamo a incominciare/vado a impiattare”). Il tutto a mio immodesto avviso, ovviamente.

Comment: @DaG: In che senso sarebbe "appena un gradino al di sopra"?

Comment: @DaG "Sono  a presentarvi il celebre oratore" suona molto innaturale a me. "Sono a trovare un amico" suona perfettamente normale (e infatti la uso spesso). Non so bene come precisare meglio queste impressioni però...

Comment: @DenisNardin: Non dico che “sono a presentarvi” sia “buon” italiano, ma se lo googli vedrai che è piuttosto frequente, spesso in testi che danno l'idea di avere pretese di formalità, magari al di sopra delle capacità di chi scrive (“con la presente sono a presentarvi la nuova pagina”, “con grande entusiasmo sono a presentarvi le attività” e simili). Invece non credo di aver mai sentito “sono a trovare” e non sono neppure sicurissimo del senso: “sono a trovare un amico” sarebbe un sinonimo di “sono da un amico”, “sono in visita da un amico”?

Comment: @Charo: Un gradino al di sopra nella scala che ha in fondo forme affettate e ricercate (ma con esito non all'altezza) e in cima forme normali e quotidiane.

Comment: @DaG Esatto (ma potrebbe essere solo il mio idioletto -- cercando frasi simili su google come "sono a farmi un giro" si trovano principalmente recensioni di posti nel nord est)

Comment: Veramente, non saprei dire se rientri nell'accezione di "stare" menzionata da @DaG. Forse sono io, ma vedo un senso diverso in tutti gli esempi del numero 11.b del Treccani.

Comment: @Charo: In quell'accezione registrata dal Treccani ci sono esempi come “stette un pezzo a pensarci su” e “stavano ancora lì a chiacchierare”, che mi sembrano non lontani da “sono stato a trovare un amico”. Comunque è vero, c'è la questione dei tempi verbali diversi. Bisogna capirla meglio; c'è molto di idiomatico.

Comment: Anche per me è decisamente essere. "Sono a trovare un amico" non mi pare dialettale. Tre esempi a caso:
 https://www.lasicilia.it/news/caltanissetta/308234/gela-nell-arcaica-necropoli-del-borgo-avvenuti-nuovi-interessanti-ritrovamenti.html -> era a visitare (giornale siciliano)
https://www.ciociariaoggi.it/news/news/34694/veroli-casamari-furto-in-casa-ladri-rubano-mentre-proprietario-e-in-ospedale.html -> giornale laziale
https://notiziaoggi.it/cronaca/pensionato-sparito-da-pray-era-a-visitare-un-amico-nellossola/ -> giornale piemontese

Answer (score -1):

#### 1. Quale verbo?

Nel contesto della frase in oggetto, "Sono stato/a (a trovare)" è voce del verbo "stare", mentre "essere" è usato come ausiliare, per formare il tempo passato (come per qualsiasi verbo intransitivo) su questo non c'è alcun dubbio perché si fa riferimento alla permaneza in un luogo, non ad una condizione intrinseca del soggetto. Quella che in Spagnolo (credo, non lo conosco bene) è la differenza tre *ser* ed *estar*.

[EDIT] In seguito ad alcuni commenti, ho provato ad approfondire ulteriormente quella che a me era apparsa come una cosa evidente. Al momento ho trovato un [post dal forum dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_12/interventi/5219.shtml.html), in cui si legge:

> Se ci si riferisce a persone, il verbo stare, nell’uso moderno neutro — diversi, in parte, gli usi passati —, ha generalmente il senso di «soggiornare», «risiedere», o indica la positura, o, ovviamente, le condizioni di salute. Poi ci sono le espressioni idiomatiche, inalterabili.

Quindi, se ho ben interpretato, nella frase "sono stato a trovare una coppia di amici", dove evidentemente la permanenza non è abituale, il verbo utilizzato è **essere**, come aveva correttamente suggerito Denis Nardin. Chiedo scusa per la confusione.

#### 2. Interscambiabilità di "andare a + infinito" e "stare a + infinito"

Sono in certa misura interscambiabili ma i due costrutti hanno sfumature diverse: "andare a + infinito" pone l'accento sullo spostamento da un luogo all'altro mentre "stare a  + infinito" pone l'accento sulla permanenza per un certo periodo di tempo: "sono andato a vedere come stava" non da alcuna indicazione della durata della visita mentre "sono stato a vedere come stava" suggerisce una certa permanenza.
Certamente non sono mai interscambiabili al modo imperativo, perché hanno significati opposti.

#### 3. Tempo verbale

In linea di massima, il costrutto "stare a + infinito" può essere usato con qualsiasi tempo: "domani *starò a prendere* il sole tutto il giorno", "non vorrai più andare in nessun altro ristorante, dopo che *sarai stata a mangiare* lì".
Nel caso specifico di "stare a trovare", usato con il significato di fare visita a qualcuno, la locuzione funziona al passato o al futuro anteriore ("passerò da te alle 14:00, dopo che sarò stato a trovare una coppia di amici") ma non al presente o al futuro semplice.

Se invece è usata con altro significato, funziona benissimo anche al presente e futuro semplice (ad esempio, "suvvia, non stiamo a trovare il pelo nell'uovo!" oppure "non ho alcuna intenzione di mentire: non starò a trovare una scusa solo per non urtare la sua sensibilità").

Comment: Chi ha votato negativamente potrebbe chiarire cosa non va secondo lui/lei?

Comment: Con modo imperativo intendi, per esempio, "Stai a fare i compiti nella tua camera" e "Vai a fare i compiti nella tua camera"? In che senso queste due frasi hanno significati opposti?

Comment: @Charo, in generale "stare" (rimanere in un posto) e "andare" (lasciare il posto in cui ci si trova per raggiungerne un altro) hanno significati opposti; "vai a fare i compiti" presuppone che tu debba andare a farli da qualche altra parte (e che tu non li stia già facendo) ed è senza dubbio un ordine mentre "stai a fare i compiti" presuppone che tu ti trattenga nel posto in cui già sei per fare i compiti (che magari stai gia facendo). [continua...]

Comment: [...] Spessissimo, all'imperativo, "stai/state a + infinito" ha valore di invito o esortazione ("sta a vedere!", "sta a sentire: ...") più che di comando. Poi, naturalmente, bisogna vedere il contesto: "Taci e sta a sentire!" è ovviamente un comando.

Comment: Non ho dato un downvote, ma potresti elaborare un pochino almeno nel punto 1? A me sembra altrettanto ovvio che il verbo sia il verbo *essere* in questo caso, e non *stare* (con il caveat che questi due verbi sono spesso interscambiabili).

Comment: @DenisNardin, chiedo scusa, mi sono espresso male (ora correggo la risposta, per renderla più chiara): di per sé, poiché "stato" è il participio passato sia di "essere" che di "stare" entrambe le interpretazioni potrebbero essere corrette. Però nella frase "sono stato a trovare..." quel "sono stato" indica la permanenza in un luogo (e quindi il verbo "stare") non una mia caratteristica instrinseca (e quindi il verbo "essere").

Comment: @secan Non sono ancora convinto (perché come ho scritto nella mia risposta al tempo presente, dove i verbi sono distinguibili, io userei sempre il verbo *essere* e mai *stare* in queste espressioni, anche se questa potrebbe essere una differenza regionale)

Comment: Ho dato io il voto negativo: questa risposta è in palese contrasto con la precedente, dà per assodato che "in questo contesto è voce del verbo stare"  senza motivarlo, cosa secondo me non vera ma sicuramente quantomeno opinabile, per i motivi espressi nella risposta di Denis Nardin e relativi commenti.

Comment: Ieri sono stato a trovare Laura e abbiamo mangiato, prima ero a trovare Laura e mangiavamo, adesso sono a trovare Laura e mangiamo... A me suona semplicemente così.

Comment: Old Man of Aran e Denis Nardin, grazie per i vostri commenti, che mi hanno spinto a ricercare quella che a me sembrava una cosa evidente e correggere la mia convinzione errata. ;) Ho aggiornato la risposta, per correggere il primo punto.